# When i run this code it tells me animalIindex not defined?

Tags: javascript, loops

When i run this code it tells me `animalIindex` not defined?

```
let animal = ['lion', 'snail', 'snake', 'tiger', 'sheep', 'frog', 'cheetah', 'leopard'];
for (let animalIndex = 0; animalIndex < animal.length; animalIndex++); {
    console.log(animal[animalIndex]);
};
```

Comment: there is some extra `;`

Comment: oh, thank you so much the code has been refactored.

Comment: unrelated: 'refactoring' and 'fixing' are 2 different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let animalIndex = 0; animalIndex < animal.length; animalIndex++);
```

If you remove the semicolon at the end then it will work, semicolon means that your statement is done, but you aren't done until the for loop is over

You close the for loop so animalIndex in animal[animalIndex] is undefined.